# Python Search JSON values for Date

Tags: python, json

Ok so I'm looking for advice and suggestions on the best way to comb through json data to look for today's date/time and return the right value.

Here is a sample of what the json data looks like:

```
[
    {
        "startDateTime": "2018-04-11T14:17:00-05:00",
        "endDateTime": "2018-04-11T14:18:00-05:00",
        "oncallMember": [
            "username1"
        ],
        "shiftType": "historical"
    },
    {
        "startDateTime": "2018-04-11T14:18:00-05:00",
        "endDateTime": "2018-04-16T08:00:00-05:00",
        "oncallMember": [
            "username2"
        ],
        "shiftType": null
    },
{
        "startDateTime": "2018-04-16T08:00:00-05:00",
        "endDateTime": "2018-04-23T08:00:00-05:00",
        "oncallMember": [
            "username1"
        ],
        "shiftType": null
    },
    {
        "startDateTime": "2018-04-23T08:00:00-05:00",
        "endDateTime": "2018-04-30T08:00:00-05:00",
        "oncallMember": [
            "username2"
        ],
        "shiftType": null
    },
......continues on for the year
```

The start/end dates are set to be weekly rotations between the members, however when exceptions are set or changed, the start/end dates could vary daily or any other amount of time. What I want to do is check for today's date and find the current "oncallMember". I'm not sure how to search between the start and end times for today's date.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

the module *arrow* maybe helpful.
first,get the today's timestamp range

```
import arrow
today = arrow.now()
(day_start,day_end) = today.span('day')
day_start_timestamp = day_start.timestamp
day_end_timestamp = day_end.timestamp
```

and then you need parse detail data into timestamp,but your raw data looks like a duration of time  like "2018-04-16T08:00:00-05:00",maybe you need slice part of it like "2018-04-16T08:00:00",and using *arrow* parse it into timestamp,like

```
raw = "2018-04-16T08:00:00"
FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS"
obj = arrow.get(raw,FORMAT)
obj_ts = obj.timestamp
```

and then you need judge whether *obj_ts* is in range between day_start_timestamp and day_end_timestamp

but if you need your code running for days,the timestamp range need to be changed everyday

Answer (score 0):

#### `json` and `datetime` libraries

Use`json` library for reading json by `json.loads` and converting it into `dictionary`

---

and for `str` to `datetime` conversion use `datetime` and `dateutil.parser.parse`

---

```
import json
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime

dict_ = json.loads(json_str)
# json str is the json you mentioned
startDate = dict_[0]['startDateTime']
# '2018-04-11T14:17:00-05:00'
date = parse(startDate)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 14, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

Once you get the date-time do further coding for start end date of today's comparison and return `oncallMember`